# Como identificar qual Tabpage esta sendo fechada

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

Galera bom dia, como vai?
Estou trabalhando com XtraTabControl, e quando fecho uma aba, preciso saber qual aba foi fechada. hoje no evento `xtraTabControl1_CloseButtonClick`, estou fazendo da seguinte maneira:

`

```
private void xtraTabControl1_CloseButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e) //click fechar aba 
        {
            ClosePageButtonEventArgs arg = e as ClosePageButtonEventArgs;
            (arg.Page as XtraTabPage).PageVisible = false;

        if (//CONDIÇÂO SOMENTE PARA A PAGE 1) // so executa se for a aba 1
        {
            foreach (Control ctl in xtraTabPage1.Controls)
            {
                if (ctl is TextEdit)
                {
                    ((TextEdit)(ctl)).Text = string.Empty;
                }

                if (ctl is TextBox)
                {
                    ((TextBox)(ctl)).Text = string.Empty;
                }
            }

            id_v = 0;
            gridControl2.DataSource = null;
            gridView2.Columns.Clear();
            gridView1.ActiveFilterString = "";
        }
    }`
```

Alguem poderia me ajudar com a condição do IF?

Valeu

Comment: Oi Thomas! O arg.Page (2° comando) não contém informações necessárias para sua verificação?

Comment: Exatamente, nao tinha reparado. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

galera consegui,

Fiz a condição da seguinte maneira:

```
arg.Page == xtraTabPage1
```

Codigo final:

```
private void xtraTabControl1_CloseButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e) //click fechar aba 
    {
        ClosePageButtonEventArgs arg = e as ClosePageButtonEventArgs;
        (arg.Page as XtraTabPage).PageVisible = false;

        if (arg.Page == xtraTabPage1) // so executa se for a aba um
        {
            foreach (Control ctl in xtraTabPage1.Controls)
            {
                if (ctl is TextEdit)
                {
                    ((TextEdit)(ctl)).Text = string.Empty;
                }

                if (ctl is TextBox)
                {
                    ((TextBox)(ctl)).Text = string.Empty;
                }
            }

            id_v = 0;
            gridControl2.DataSource = null;
            gridView2.Columns.Clear();
            gridView1.ActiveFilterString = "";
        }
    }
```

Valeu